# Stripped hole in furnace fan housing assembly

Tags: metal

In the furnace blower housing, where the blower motor sits, the holes have gotten may be a little bigger. This is a thin piece of metal where the screw sits. But now my screw keeps rotating. On two screws, I have put put a nut to tighten the bolt, but for one hole, I cannot put a nut because once the blower is there, my hand wont reach.

I have tried everbilt mr. grip but that doesn't help much. I can't run the A/C because of this (the same fan supplies cold air in summer from A/C). Really appreciate any ideas. Is it easier to drill a new hole? I tried but couldn't do it with the screw. May be I need to use a drill bit?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I don't understand your question, what is the work you are trying to do? By furnace do you mean heater? What is the make, model and year of the car?

Comment: I don't think he is talking about a car. Perhaps a home renovation site on stack exchange would be a better fit for this question.

Answer (score 1):

I would solder a nut with the matching thread to the thin piece of metal, more than sufficient to hold the nut in place.

Answer (score 0):

Can you install a bolt from the other side? If so put a split lock washer on the bolt  which will dig into the metal as you tighten and keep it from spinning.